# Neo4J - SQL to CQL - Relations and Joins

Tags: neo4j

I have two tables, described as below.

**Table 1: countries**

```
c_id, int
c_name, varchar(20) (PK)
```

Sample records in this table are.

```
c_id | c_name
1 | USA
2 | UK
3 | PK
```

**Table 2: immigrants**

```
i_id, int
i_name, varchar(20)
i_country, int (FK)
```

Sample records in this table are.

```
i_id | i_name | i_country
1 | John | 1
2 | Graham | 2
3 | Ali | 3
```

**Question 1:**

I want to create two nodes (tables) in Neo4J along with data types.
I can create the nodes by using the following syntax, but I do not know how to define data types.

```
CREATE (country:Country {c_id:1,c_name:"PK"}) RETURN country
```

**QUESTION 2:**

I am unable to understand how to create relations between two nodes on PK and FK, please provide syntax for creating a relation between the above two nodes.

**QUESTION 3:**

What is the CQL for producing the following output.

```
i_id | i_name | i_country | c_id | c_name
1 | John | 1 | 1 | USA
2 | Graham | 2 | UK
3 | Ali 3 | PK
```

Answer (score 0):

### Question 1

You don't define data types in neo4j. On different nodes you can store different data types for the same key.

### Question 2

You can create a relationship like this:

```
MATCH (i:Immigrant {i_id: 2}), (c:Country {c_id: 1})
CREATE (i)-[:MIGRATED]->(c)
```

### Question 3

It's 'Cypher' not 'CQL'. I think you want to `MATCH` `Immigrant` nodes to `Country` nodes:

```
MATCH (i:Immigrant)-[:MIGRATED]->(c:Country)
RETURN i.i_id, i.name, c.c_id, c.name
```

Comment: Thank you! Question 1: OK. Question 2: It does create a relation, but only to one record. I need to create it for all records. Further, I understand, joins should be on fields, then why you have used values like: MATCH (i:Immigrant {i_id: 2}), (c:Country {c_id: 1})

Comment: There are no joins and fields. There are nodes connected by relationships. Both nodes and relationships have properties. Properties are key-value pairs. The query matches two nodes (`Country` and `Immigrant`) to create a relationship between them. If you want to do this for all records, you have to do it programmatically or e.g. by loading a CSV file: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html

Comment: If you truly want to embrace the graph paradigm, why don't you get rid of those "primary keys" in your tables? You can truly do without them, as you won't be storying those elsewhere (in RDBMs, they are needed for linking table rows to other tables through "foreign" key usage). Not needed in Graph. You can actually replace for true keys (ISO country codes, etc.) if you want to enforce uniqueness by any other means.